# Best practices of db connection pool handling in a node js app?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I'm referring to [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) package below, but I guess this question is rather generic.

There is this trivial [example](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Example) where you 1) acquire (connect) a connection (client) from the pool in the top level http request handler, 2) do all business inside of that handler and 3) release it back to the pool after you're done.

I guess it works fine for that example, but as soon as your app becomes somewhat bigger this becomes painfull soon.

I'm thinking of these two options, but I'm not quite sure...

1. do the "get client + work + release client" approach everywhere I need to talk to db.

   This seems like a good choice, but will it not lead to eating up more than one connection/client per the top http request (there are parallel async db calls in many places in my project)?
2. try to assign a globaly shared reference to **one** client/connection accessible via `require()`

   Is this a good idea and actually reasonably doable? Is it possible to nicely handle the "back to the pool release" in all ugly cases (errors in parallel async stuff for example)?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do that at all. Instead, trust a high-level library like [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) do all that for you automatically.

Comment: thanks @vitaly-t, I will take a look at the pg-promise

Comment: I have worked on several web apps and can tell you that every one which uses the pin-a-db-connection-to-the-request model has inevitably ended up with scalability problems from the way it handles database resources.  (Get + Use + Return) is superior in my book.  So many fewer things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I lost some time trying to figure that out. At the end, after some consideration and influenced by [John Papa's code](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/zza-node-mongo) I decided use a `database` module like this:

```
var Q = require('q');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.getDb = getDb;

var db = null;

function getDb() {
  return Q.promise(theDb);

  function theDb(resolve, reject, notify) {
    if (db) {
      resolve(db);
    } else {
      MongoClient.connect(mongourl, mongoOptions, function(err, theDb) {            
          resolve(db);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I need to perform a query:

```
getDb().then(function(db) {

    //performe query here

});
```

At least for Mongodb this is good practice as seen [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have not tried your code, but I think I see the point. You are showing how to have one global db instance (point 2 in my original question). But, how is the releasing done (if with mongoclient there is such thing)?

Comment: I unaware of the need for releasing in Mongo, forgot about that in the answer. It looks like this solution its not good for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The best advise would depend on the type of database and the basic framework that represents the database.

In case of Postgres, the basic framework/driver is [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), which has embedded support for connection pool. That support is however low-level.

For high-level access see [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which provides automatic connection management, support for [tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks), [transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions) and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what has worked well for me.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var config = { pg : 'postgres://localhost/postgres' };

pg.connect(config.pg, function(err, client, done) {
  client.query('SELECT version();', function (err, results) {
    done();

    //do something with results.rows
  });
});
```